# Why event listeners are not getting removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('restart')[0].addEventListener('click', init);
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.row div');
let bombTile = [];

init();


 function clickHand(tile, index) {
    if (bombTile.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
        bombClicked(tile , index);
    } else {
        flipMe(tile, index);
    }
}


function bombClicked(tile ,index) {
    tile.classList.add('bomb');
    bombTile.forEach(e => {
        tiles[e].classList.add('bomb');
        tiles[e].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>';
    })
    document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].classList.add('bombed');
    
}

function flipMe(tile , index) {
    tile.classList.add('active');
    tile.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-sun"></i>';
    tile.removeEventListener('click' , clickHand);
}


function init() {
    bombTile = []
    while (bombTile.length < 10) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
        if (bombTile.indexOf(r) === -1) bombTile.push(r);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].classList.remove('bombed')
    tiles.forEach((tile, index) => {
        tile.addEventListener('click',  clickHand.bind(this,tile , index));
        tile.className = '';
        tile.innerHTML = '';

    })
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(233,233,233,.9), rgba(0,0,0,.8)) , url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/540/thumb-1920-540654.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.row{
    width: 540px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.row.bombed{
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.row div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,.8);
    border: 1px solid #000;

    transition: all .3s ease;

}

.row div.active{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #000;
}

.row div.active i{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.row div.bomb{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: #f00;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.restart:link,
.restart:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.restart:hover{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
      transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }
    
    20%, 80% {
      transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }
  
    30%, 50%, 70% {
      transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }
  
    40%, 60% {
      transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bomber</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f80fd99102.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>
        Bomber
    </h1>
    <div class="bomber-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="restart">
        New Game
    </a>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a simple bomber game where 10 tiles have bomb in it. Once user click a bomb game ends.

What my problem is when I click on any tile, I want to remove event listen attached to it. If user clicks on tile that have bomb I want to remove event listener from each tile.

I added code to remove event listener but it is not working somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an event listener you have to pass the **same** function to `removeEventListener` that you pass to `addEventListener`.

> ```
> tile.removeEventListener('click' , clickHand);
>
> tile.addEventListener('click',  clickHand.bind(this,tile , index));
> ```

You are trying to remove `clickHand` but you added a *new* function generated by calling `bind` on `clickHand`.

---

An easier approach for this would probably be to change `clickHand` so it checked the state of the tile and determined if it had already been clicked (and then returning without doing anything else if it has).

Answer (score 0):

The reason `removeListener` might not work is you are creating a new function every time you are using `.bind`. The removeEventListener expects the same function that is being used as handler in addEventListener.

What you are doing is,

```js
tile.addEventListener('click',  clickHand.bind(this,tile , index));
```

So you can't remove using

```js
tile.removeEventListener('click',  clickHand);
```

To properly remove it, do something like this,

```js
let tileHandler =  clickHand.bind(this,tile , index)
tile.addEventListener('click',  tileHandler);

// Then remove by
tile.removeEventListener('click',  tileHandler);
```

But there are a lot of tiles and you have to keep a record for every new handler created. So what you can do is have a flag for whether the game is over or not. And if it is, then prevent the tiles from flipping.

Add a flag

```
let gameOver;
```

In your click function

```
else if(!gameOver){
        flipMe(tile, index);
    }
}
```

And in your `bombClicked()` function add,

```
gameOver=true;
```

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('restart')[0].addEventListener('click', init);
var tiles = document.querySelectorAll('.row div');
let bombTile = [];
let gameOver = false;
init();


 function clickHand(tile, index) {
    if (bombTile.indexOf(index) !== -1) {
        bombClicked(tile , index);
    } else if(!gameOver){
        flipMe(tile, index);
    }
}


function bombClicked(tile ,index) {
    gameOver=true;
    tile.classList.add('bomb');
    bombTile.forEach(e => {
        tiles[e].classList.add('bomb');
        tiles[e].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-bomb"></i>';
    })
    document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].classList.add('bombed');
    
}

function flipMe(tile , index) {
    tile.classList.add('active');
    tile.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-sun"></i>';
    tile.removeEventListener('click' , clickHand);
}


function init() {
    bombTile = []
    while (bombTile.length < 10) {
        var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 1;
        if (bombTile.indexOf(r) === -1) bombTile.push(r);
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName('row')[0].classList.remove('bombed')
    tiles.forEach((tile, index) => {
        tile.addEventListener('click',  clickHand.bind(this,tile , index));
        tile.className = '';
        tile.innerHTML = '';

    })
}
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(233,233,233,.9), rgba(0,0,0,.8)) , url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/540/thumb-1920-540654.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.row{
    width: 540px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

.row.bombed{
    animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

h1{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.row div{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgba(200,200,200,.8);
    border: 1px solid #000;

    transition: all .3s ease;

}

.row div.active{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background-color: #000;
}

.row div.active i{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.row div.bomb{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    background: #f00;
    font-size: 20px;
}


.restart:link,
.restart:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: white;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.restart:hover{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
      transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }
    
    20%, 80% {
      transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }
  
    30%, 50%, 70% {
      transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }
  
    40%, 60% {
      transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bomber</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f80fd99102.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <h1>
        Bomber
    </h1>
    <div class="bomber-grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#!" class="restart">
        New Game
    </a>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```